# Get inner text of a span in same div block as button

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i get innertext of a span which is in a div block with a button.

html code

```
<div class='itemDivImage'>
    <a href =" .$link_to_page. ">
        <img src=" .$read_row['Bild']." alt=" .$name. "/>
    </a>
    <br>
    <span>".$name."</span>
    <br>
    <span class='price'> Pris:
       <span class='penger2'> ". $read_row['Pris'] ."</span> kr
    </span>
    <br>
    <input type="button" name="' .$name. '" class="bayItem" value="Lägg i varukorg">
    <img src="'.$linkImgAAA. '" class="energysafe" alt="EnergySafe" />
</div>
<div>
    <img id="varukorg_img" src="img/varukorg.png" alt="Varukorg" name="0">
    <a href="#">Varukorg <span class="penger">0</span> kr</a>
```

Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.bayItem').click(function(){

        var penger = $('.penger').text();
        var penger2 = $('.penger2').text();

        penger = parseInt(penger);
        penger2 = parseInt(penger2);
            var result = penger + penger2;
            $('.penger').text(result);
            });

});
```

Comment: can you please explain better what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: Can't see any element with `class="penger"` which you are trying to access  `var penger = $('.penger').text();`

Comment: No `penger` class in your html

Comment: I have 5 divs on page. that what I need is to get inner text of span which is in the same div block as button. Because all buttons and span have the same class name. I need maybe like use "This" but it works in my code only for button

Comment: $('.penger').text(); is in my header file.

Comment: You need a span element from the same element a clicked button is positioned? But which span, there are two spans on the div block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `$('.penger')` it returns all matching spans across the document.

To limit to the one you want, first go up from your button to the wrapping div and then down again to the related span, eg:

```
$(".bayItem").click(function() {
    var wrapper = $(this).closest(".itemDivImage");
    var span = wrapper.find(".penger");
    console.log(span.text());
});
```

Example snippet:

```js
$(".bayItem").click(function() {
  var wrapper = $(this).closest(".itemDivImage");
  var span = wrapper.find(".penger");
  console.log(span.text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='itemDivImage'>
  <span>Row 1</span>
  <span class='price'> Pris:
       <span class='penger'>12.34</span> kr
  </span>
  <br>
  <input type="button" class="bayItem" value="Lägg i varukorg" />
</div>
<hr/>
<div class='itemDivImage'>
  <span>Row 2</span>
  <span class='price'> Pris:
       <span class='penger'>23.45</span> kr
  </span>
  <br>
  <input type="button" class="bayItem" value="Lägg i varukorg" />
</div>
<hr/>
<div class='itemDivImage'>
  <span>Row 3</span>
  <span class='price'> Pris:
       <span class='penger'>34.56</span> kr
  </span>
  <br>
  <input type="button" class="bayItem" value="Lägg i varukorg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

find:

```
$(".bayItem").on('click', function () {
    console.log($(".itemDivImage").find("span").text());
})
```

You can change this script according to your needs

Comment: and how can i find a span by class name? as you can see the html code I have more span and with you code I get inner text of all span elements

Comment: in the method "find" you can use any jquery selectors https://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: As I wrote I have 5 divs with same class names and spans have same class names. If iI change "span" in you code to class name which I need to get information, than I get value of all 5 spans. But I need to get value of a spicific. Maybe have I to use like "This" ?

Answer (score 0):

you must use "closure" 
for example:

```
var items = $(".itemDivImage");
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".bayItem").on('click', get_text());
function get_text () {
    //console.log(items);
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        (function (index) { //means i counter
            console.log($(items[index]).find("span").text());
        })(i);
    }
 }
});
```